# Idioma com Dialeto

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas, linguística, acentos-ou-sotaques, dialetos

Existem algumas coisas que, dependendo da região do Brasil, tem um nome completamente diferente, como, por exemplo: a abóbora que pode ser chamada de jerimum; teju, teiú e tiú; mexerica e tangerina, etc. Algumas expressões também têm sentido completamente diferente. A pronúncia também denuncia a diferença de regiões.

No entanto, no Brasil, dizem que não existe dialeto, só sotaque.

Isso me faz pensar: existe um limiar que define um dialeto? O que diferencia uma língua de um dialeto? Quem define isso?

Comment: Um sábio disse uma vez que [uma língua é um dialeto com forças armadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy).

Comment: Subscrevo que no Brasil não existe dialeto. Em minha visão, dialeto é o que se encontra em: Norte e Sul da Itália em relação à língua italiana; Alemanha e Suíça em relação à língua alemã. No Brasil, a língua permanece a mesma apenas com algumas preferências naturais de gíria e pronúncia.

Comment: Respostas explicando se existem ou não dialetos no Brasil e citando quais são, autenticam a pergunta como pertencente ao site PL. Já a mera distinção entre dialeto e língua, cabe melhor no site de linguística.  Essa é minha **opinião** (antes que alguém venha rebater)

Comment: Paulo, nota que [jirimu](https://www.priberam.com/dlpo/jerimum) é um tipo de abóbora; chamar todas de jerimú é [sinédoque](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin%C3%A9doque).

Comment: O português brasileiro o o português de Portugal não têm dialetos. O que têm são diferenças ou variações regionais no vocabulário e sotaque. Isso sim.

Comment: @Lambie O significado que você atribui à palavra *dialeto* é distinto daquele dos [dicionários](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dialect), "a form of a language that is spoken [...] by a particular group of people" e dos [acadêmicos](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/varieties-of-english/what-is-a-dialect), "marked off from others by distinctive linguistic features. Such a variety could be associated with a particular place or region or, rather more surprisingly, it might also be associated with a certain social group—male or female, young or old, and so on.".

Comment: Também [em português](http://www.aulete.com.br/dialeto): "1. Ling. Variante de uma língua restrita a uma comunidade inserida em uma comunidade maior de mesma língua [Divide-se em dialeto social e geográfico]

2. Ling. Qualquer variedade linguistica coexistente com outra e que não pode ser considerada uma língua (dialeto caipira)".

Comment: @stafusa Sugiro essa leitura: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect Dialeto no sentido largo e não restrito, não existe  no Brasil. Dialetos no sentido restrito, existe. Como sou tradutora, tenho muito cuidado com isso. Para mim, existem duas grandes variedades de português: o do Brasil e o do Portugal. Diferenças de sotaque e vocabulário regional não são provas de dialetos. O Black English é um dialeto do inglês americano, por exemplo. Que eu saiba tal fenômeno não existe nem no Brasil nem em Portugal. Deixemos o assunto; não tem manera de chegarmos à um acordo.

Comment: @Lambie Eu cito justamente esse verbete na minha resposta, então é óbvio que o conheço e li. Essa não é uma questão de tradução, mas sim de linguística. É ponto pacífico que muitas vezes conseguimos distinguir a região de origem de uma pessoa através de características de vocabulário, gramática e sotaque: ou seja, o diferente modo de falar claramente se trata de (da Wikipedia) "*a variety of a language that is a characteristic of a particular group*". É curiosa essa resistência ao uso do termo dialeto. [Todo mundo fala um dialeto de sua língua.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/812).

Comment: Dialectal differences are really big: **I'm going to** the movies. [regular English]. **I be going** to the movies, [Black English, different ***grammar***] No Brasil, Eu vou pro cinema, Eu vou para o cinema=se diz em todo o país. Para mim, não considero, como já disse, diferenças de vocabulário ou sotaque como dialeto. A gramática precisa ser completamente diferente. Tipo crioulo Cabo Verdeano. Ou o português que se fala em Casamança. Agora vou deixar esse assunto porque ficou repetiendo a mesma coisa. Não todo mundo não fala um "dialeto".

Answer (score 4):

Sim, [há dialetos no Brasil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro#Dialetos_do_portugu%C3%AAs_brasileiro).

O fato de os falantes das diferentes *variedades* do português brasileiro:

- se entenderem mutuamente (em alto grau);
- compartilharem um cerne lexical e gramático; e
- se referirem às mesmas autoridades (dicionários, Academia Brasileira de Letras, etc.);

mostra que estas variedades não poderiam ser consideradas *línguas* diferentes. Mas, sim, ao menos no sentido linguístico [mais aceito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect#Terminology), de que toda variedade linguística é um dialeto, são sim dialetos.

Vale notar que não há definição universalmente aceita do termo, e a influência de aspectos sociais e políticos (leia-se *status*) são provavelmente inevitáveis. Talvez até por isso não se goste de falar popularmente em dialetos no Brasil. Outra possibilidade é que se associe o conceito de dialeto a diferenças maiores, como as que existem entre dialetos em países como Itália e Alemanha (que muitas vezes são tão distintos entre si ao ponto de não serem mutuamente inteligíveis), que não ocorrem no português.

Segundo a Wikipedia (fontes na descrição da [imagem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficheiro:Portugueselanguagedialects-Brazil.png)) se distinguem 16 dialetos no Brasil:

[image]

Comment: Não acho que nível de formação seja uma diferença de dialeto. No Brazil e em Portugal existem regionalismos ou vocabulários específicos, nada disso constitui **uma diferença dialetal**. Wikipedia está cheinho de erros. No Brazil existem variações regionais e sotaques. Para chegar a um diferença dialelal, é preciso de diferenças básicas na estrutura da língua. A estrutura básica do português é a mesma coisa em todo o país.

Comment: @Lambie Em verbetes consolidados, a Wikipedia tem em média tantos erros quanto enciclopédias consagradas. Não questiono tua afirmação, não sou linguista, mas se você tem fontes que embasariam uma resposta diferente, seria muito bom que você a postasse: isso só contribuiria para tornar esse fórum mais rico.

Comment: A diferença dialetal precisa ser estrutural. Não só sotoques e regionalismos. Você discorda que no Brasil inteiro a estrutura básica da língua é a mesma? Então, não podem ser dialetos. Eu falo com sotaque carioca, minha amiga com sotaque mineiro e meu amigo com sotaque paulista, portanto os tres fizemos curso superior. Isso seria dialetos diferentes?

Comment: @Lambie Com meus modestos conhecimentos e minhas fontes, escrevi uma resposta - volto a sugerir que você faça o mesmo. Como disse antes, não questiono tua afirmação e não sou linguista; a resposta que postei é uma proposta, não uma tese que eu esteja defendendo. E esse também na verdade não é o fórum adequado para discutir a definição de dialeto. Lembro uma vez mais que as fontes (livros, teses, artigos) daquele mapa de dialetos podem ser encontradas na [descrição do arquivo ("Origem")](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficheiro:Portugueselanguagedialects-Brazil.png).

Comment: Wikipedia serviria de fonte se esse artigo disposse de um selo qualitativo no canto superior direito. Concordo com @Lambie, se 'paulistano' e 'carioquês' (ambos termos me parecem neologismos) fossem dialetos, no próprio RJ-cidade haveria dialetos diferentes — das favelas e dos bairros de elite.

Comment: @WilliamLio E há, são os chamados *dialetos sociais*. Do [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/dialeto): "1. Ling. Variante de uma língua restrita a uma comunidade inserida em uma comunidade maior de mesma língua [Divide-se em dialeto social e geográfico]

2. Ling. Qualquer variedade linguistica coexistente com outra e que não pode ser considerada uma língua (dialeto caipira)".

Comment: @WilliamLio Em inglês: [dicionário da Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dialect), "a form of a language that is spoken [...] by a particular group of people". Descrição de um [acadêmico](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/varieties-of-english/what-is-a-dialect), "marked off from others by distinctive linguistic features. Such a variety could be associated with a particular place or region or, rather more surprisingly, it might also be associated with a certain social group—male or female, young or old, and so on.".

Comment: Caros William Lio, Lambie e Stafusa, percebo que, realmente, não existe uma "linha" limitando o que é uma língua, o que é dialeto e, tampouco sotaque. O texto que @stafusa colocou (descrição do arquivo) indica, na descrição do ficheiro, como referência, várias obras. O próprio título de cada obra demonstra que não há qualquer acordo a respeito do que é dialeto, fala ou sotaque, que dirá dar-lhes limite. Pelo jeito toda a matéria relacionada a linguística (como tal nos sugere discutir Centaurus) e que é lecionada nas universidades está baseada em opiniões e não há **quem** as regulamente.